# Progress Bar in webBrowser is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, progress-bar

I have a method where i am setting my progress bar in web Browser.

```
public static void SetProgressIndicator(bool isVisible)
{          
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = isVisible;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;
}

public void WebBrowser_Loaded()
{
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();  //creating object       
        SetProgressIndicator(true);
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading...";
        this.WebBrowser.Navigate(uri);
}
```

So when the navigation fails this method will be invoked

```
 void WebBrowser_NavigationFailed()
{
    SetProgressIndicator(false);//Progress-bar should stop here
    MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, PLease try again later");
}
```

Problem is :  Progress bar is getting created but after navigating in to WebBrowser_NavigationFailed() method , progress bar should stop.But it is not stopping and getting displayed above the pop-up Message-box.How to make the progress-bar to stop.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: set a break point to this line `SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;`, is it hit more than twice? is it set to true in the last time?

Comment: Use : `DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();`

Comment: @ kennyzx . the  `SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = isVisible;` hits twice and it is set to "false" n the last time.